# Chromecast - Added another application - not visible

Tags: android, chromecast

I've added another application in the chromecast dev console so that i can work in parallel to the production release. I've changed the app_id in my application to point to the new applciation i've created in the dev console. I waited around 40 mins now, device selection does not show up in my android app.

Comment: Reboot your chromecast device. It usually takes 6 hours for new app id's to be sent to all Chromecast devices. A reboot will force a fetch of all the app id's.

Comment: @LeonNicholls nope .. that did not work..